# R: apply function to each element of the matrix of lists and return result in the same matrix format

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply

Let's say I have a matrix of lists:

```
theList <- matrix(list(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10)), nrow=2, ncol=2)
theList
     [,1]       [,2]
[1,] Numeric,10 Numeric,10
[2,] Numeric,10 Numeric,10
```

And I want to apply some function to each element of this matrix while retaining the original dimensions.

I found that the following works with sapply:

```
apply(theList, 2, sapply, mean)
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.5678905 0.0577225
[2,] -0.2708252 0.5045110
```

However it does not work with lapply:

```
apply(theList, 2, lapply, mean)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0.5678905

[[1]][[2]]
[1] -0.2708252


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.0577225

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 0.504511
```

How to apply a function to each list in the matrix of lists and return the data in the same format - matrix of lists with the same dimensions?

Comment: A matrix of lists is a terrible data structure.  Also, why do you care about `lapply()` if `sapply()` worked fine?

Comment: It would be a nice enough structure for me if this worked. I don't want `sapply` because it is limited to functions that return single value as output. `lapply` is more general and consistent.

Comment: I suppose `simplify2array(apply(theList, 2, lapply, mean))` would work.  Or even `\`dim<-\`(lapply(theList, mean), dim(theList))`

Comment: I agree. Not sure to understand either but maybe you would like to have lists in each cell of the matrix? If yes, this does the job `apply(theList, 1:2, function(x) list(sapply(x, mean)))`

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff yes, those seem to be working. Thanks a lot. Just wish it was simpler than that. Wonder if `plyr` would have anything of help here..
@VincentBonhomme - What is that apply with two margins in one call? `apply(theList, 1:2, lapply, mean)` seems to be working, but not sure what it does.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius Please call `set.seed()` when generating randomized data so everyone can reproduce your sessions exactly. (Not exactly a big deal for this question, but in general it's good to do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not costly to rebuild a matrix out of a vector or list, since it only sets the `dim` attribute on the object. So I would do this:

```
res <- matrix(lapply(theList,mean),nrow(theList));
res;
##      [,1]       [,2]
## [1,] -0.1956084 0.03062223
## [2,] -0.2106935 0.1842444
```

Note that although the above result displays exactly like a matrix of doubles, it is still in fact a matrix of lists:

```
str(res);
## List of 4
##  $ : num -0.196
##  $ : num -0.211
##  $ : num 0.0306
##  $ : num 0.184
##  - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks +1. I had a similar approach of making matrix from result in mind. But was looking for a "more elegant" solution. For now found out that `plyr` package `llply` seems to be doing the job well. But in base R this answer you gave is the best so far.

Answer (score 1):

What about this, There are lots of function in `purrr` for mapping function in the case like yours,

```
library(purrr)
apply(theList, 2, map_dbl, mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this approach from `plyr` is working:

```
library(plyr)
llply(theList, range)
         [,1]      [,2]
[1,] Numeric,2 Numeric,2
[2,] Numeric,2 Numeric,2
```